# Rank non zeros elements column by column in a sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix and want to rank its non zero elements column by column. The approach I use now is to convert all zeros to `NA`. The problem with this approach is, the matrix isn't sparse any more and having space complexities while doing so.

Is there any way to use function `rank` without converting zeros to `NA`? Reproducible example:

```
library(Matrix)

TestMatrix = Matrix(c(0,100,12,0,11,
                      0,100,12,0,11,
                      0,100,12,0,11,
                      0,100,12,0,11,
                      0,100,12,0,11), 5, sparse = TRUE)

TestMatrix = replace(TestMatrix, TestMatrix == 0, NA)

apply(-TestMatrix, 2, function(x) {rank(x, na.last = TRUE)})
```

I want a sparse matrix of the same size, with non-zero values replaced by column-wise rank.

Comment: Are the non-zero vales in your matrix really all positive as in your example?

Comment: Yes. All the values are positive.

Comment: I should have updated that in the question. Yes, my expected output is a sparse matrix of the same dimension, but with non-zero values replaced by rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example `TestMatrix`:

```
#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                        
#[1,]   .   .   .   .   .
#[2,] 100 100 100 100 100
#[3,]  12  12  12  12  12
#[4,]   .   .   .   .   .
#[5,]  11  11  11  11  11
```

> I want a sparse matrix of the same size, with non-zero values replaced by column-wise rank.

```
n <- diff(TestMatrix@p)  ## number of non-zeros per column
lst <- split(TestMatrix@x, rep.int(1:ncol(TestMatrix), n))  ## columns to list
r <- unlist(lapply(lst, rank))  ## column-wise ranking and result collapsing
RankMatrix <- TestMatrix  ## copy sparse matrix
RankMatrix@x <- r  ## replace non-zero elements with rank

#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#              
#[1,] . . . . .
#[2,] 3 3 3 3 3
#[3,] 2 2 2 2 2
#[4,] . . . . .
#[5,] 1 1 1 1 1
```