# A fast way to rank each column in a sparse matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sparse-matrix, rank

I have a `dgCMatrix` sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(1)
mat <- Matrix(c(0,0,2:0), 3,5)
rownames(mat) <- paste0("g",1:3)
colnames(mat) <- paste0("c",1:5)
```

And I want to rank each column in descending order in a `dplyr::dense_rank()` manner such that ties receive the same rank with no gaps.

The output that I'm looking for is a `data.frame` where each row has both `mat`'s `colnames`, `rownames`, and the `rank`s.

I'm currently using this `do.call` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:ncol(mat),function(x){
  data.frame(cell=colnames(mat)[x],gene_name = rownames(mat),value=mat[,x]) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(value)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(rank=dplyr::dense_rank(desc(value)))
}))
```

But looking for something faster. I know my question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772943/rank-non-zeros-elements-column-by-column-in-a-sparse-matrix) but not identical because the `split` used in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772943/rank-non-zeros-elements-column-by-column-in-a-sparse-matrix) doesn't retain `rownames`.

Answer (score 0):

Coercing from `CsparseMatrix` to `TsparseMatrix` and operating on the result is probably most natural here:

```r
library(Matrix)
set.seed(0)
m <- 6L
n <- 6L
x <- rsparsematrix(m, n, 0.5, rand.x = function(n) trunc(rnorm(n, 0, 2)))
dimnames(x) <- list(paste0("r", seq_len(m)), paste0("c", seq_len(n)))
x
```

```
6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
r1  0 -1  . -2  .  1
r2  .  . -1  .  0  .
r3  . -2  .  0  0  .
r4 -2  1  .  0  .  0
r5  .  0  .  0  .  .
r6  .  . -1  2  .  0
```

```r
denseRank <- function(x, ...) match(x, sort(unique(x), ...))
y <- as(x, "TsparseMatrix")
d <- data.frame(row = y@Dimnames[[1L]][y@i+1L],
                col = y@Dimnames[[2L]][y@j+1L],
                val = y@x,
                ran = unsplit(lapply(split(y@x, y@j), denseRank, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA), y@j))
d
```

```
   row col val ran
1   r1  c1   0   1
2   r4  c1  -2   2
3   r1  c2  -1   3
4   r3  c2  -2   4
5   r4  c2   1   1
6   r5  c2   0   2
7   r2  c3  -1   1
8   r6  c3  -1   1
9   r1  c4  -2   3
10  r3  c4   0   2
11  r4  c4   0   2
12  r5  c4   0   2
13  r6  c4   2   1
14  r2  c5   0   1
15  r3  c5   0   1
16  r1  c6   1   1
17  r4  c6   0   2
18  r6  c6   0   2
```

```r
z <- y
z@x <- as.double(d$ran)
z
```

```
6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
r1  1  3  .  3  .  1
r2  .  .  1  .  1  .
r3  .  4  .  2  1  .
r4  2  1  .  2  .  2
r5  .  2  .  2  .  .
r6  .  .  1  1  .  2
```

Some care is needed if the matrix contains `NA`.  The above passes `na.last = NA` to `denseRank`, so that `NA` values get `NA` ranks; this is consistent with `dplyr::dense_rank`.  If you want `NA` values to be assigned the least or greatest rank, then you must pass `na.last = FALSE` or `na.last = TRUE`, respectively.